# what kind of auth flow react-aad-msal uses

Tags: reactjs, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am wondering what type of authentication react-aad-msal library is using? I assume it uses implicit flow?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current newest version on master branch refers to the `msal` package: https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad/blob/3ddba649c992d2235c54636b73dfdf306922a84a/packages/react-aad-msal/package.json#L80.

This means it uses implicit flow.

If the library is updated to use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser`, it will then use authorization code flow with PKCE.

Comment: that's exact the answer!  Hawk you need to check the documentation, on the page https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad#readme says that clearly.